# SSIS string casting error

Tags: database, unicode, casting, ssis

In a derived column, I added a new column with a default string "Test". I needed to convert that string into a unicode string so I casted it - `(DT_STR,20,1252)"Test"`.

If I left it as "Test" SSIS complains because it can't insert the data into a unicode field - char(20). When I run the SSIS I get the following error.

> An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.

Answer (score 0):

[Integration Services Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx)

- DT_WSTR is unicode
- DT_STR is ANSI string

If you want a non-unicode string, your expression would be 
`(DT_STR,20,1252)"Test"`

The Unicode equivalent would be `(DT_WSTR,20)"Test"`

[image]